# Function works with buffers on the stack but not in .data or .bss sections?

Tags: assembly, nasm

I have the following code:

```
global _start
extern GetStdHandle, WriteConsoleA ;kernel32.dll

section .data:
    buf times 12 db 0

section .text:
_uint32_to_string:
;void uint32_to_string(uint32_t n, char* buffer)
;buffer: 11 bytes (minimum)
    push ebp
    push ebx
    push esi
    push edi
    mov ebp, esp
    mov ebx, [ebp + 24]
    xor edi, edi
    mov eax, [ebp + 20]
    mov ecx, 10
CREATE_UINTEGER_STRING:
    xor edx, edx
    div ecx
    add dl, '0'
    mov [ebx + edi], dl
    inc edi
    cmp eax, 0
    jne CREATE_UINTEGER_STRING
    xor esi, esi
REVERSE_STRING_UNSIGNED:
    mov ecx, 2
    mov eax, edi
    xor edx, edx
    div ecx
    cmp esi, eax
    jnl REVERSE_UNSIGNED_STRING_END
    mov eax, ebx
    add eax, edi
    sub eax, esi
    dec eax
    mov cl, [ebx + esi]
    mov dl, [eax]
    mov [ebx + esi], dl
    mov [eax], cl
    inc esi
    jmp REVERSE_STRING_UNSIGNED
REVERSE_UNSIGNED_STRING_END:
    mov byte [ebx + edi], 0
    mov esp, ebp
    pop edi
    pop esi
    pop ebx
    pop ebp
    ret

_string_length:
;uint32_t string_length(const char* s)
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp
    mov ecx, [ebp + 8]
    xor eax, eax
GET_STRLEN:
    cmp byte [ecx + eax], 0
    je END_GET_STRLEN
    inc eax
    jmp GET_STRLEN
END_GET_STRLEN:
    mov esp, ebp
    pop ebp
    ret

_start:
    mov ebp, esp
    mov eax, 235 ;here is the number to be printed
    lea ebx, [buf] ;it works if instead of this line I write:
    ; sub esp, 12
    ; mov ebx, esp
    push ebx
    push eax
    call _uint32_to_string
    add esp, 8
    push ebx
    call _string_length
    add esp, 4
    mov edi, eax
    push dword -11
    call GetStdHandle
    push dword 0
    push dword 0
    push edi
    push ebx
    push eax
    call WriteConsoleA
    mov esp, ebp
    xor eax, eax
    ret
```

I am using this program to print a number on the console screen. The problem is that if, for some reason, I choose to pass a buffer allocated in `.data` to the _uint32_to_string function, the program gives me a runtime error and exits with a gibberish exit code. If I try to define the buffer in the `.bss` section like the following, NASM gives me a warning (and the program still exits with garbage status if I run it):

```
section .bss:
    buf resb 12
;error: print_program.asm:5: warning: uninitialised space declared in non-BSS section `.bss:': zeroing
```

Luckily, if I allocate the buffer on the stack the program works correctly, prints the number and exits with status zero.

Can anybody please help me understand why the program works with buffers allocated on the stack but not with `.data` or `.bss` ones?

P.S: If it matters, here is how I compile my code (platform: Windows 10 32-bit):

```
nasm -f win32 -o print_program.obj print_program.asm
golink print_program.obj /console /entry _start kernel32.dll
```

Comment: It's `section .bss`, not `section .bss:`.  The same for `section .data`.  After you're done writing to these sections, you need to switch back to `.text` for your code or your code is going to be assembled to `.data` or `.bss`.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to include the `.text` section in my sample. I actually have it in my code and it doesn't work :(

Comment: Have you fixed the other issue I mentioned?

Comment: Update: I have removed the `:` from the sections and it works. Unfortunately, I still get that warning if I use the .bss section (but the code apparently works fine).

Comment: Please post the exact code that generates the warning.

Comment: I did, second code caption. Just replace the .data section with that and the error pops up at the `resb` line.

Comment: That section again has a colon after the section name.  Is that the exact code you have tried?  If yes, remove the colon and it should work.

Comment: Sorry, it was the `.section .text:` which I forgot to correct (remove the `:`). I just did it for the `.data` and `.bss` and missed the code part :) Now it works, thanks.

Comment: That's why it's important to post the exact and complete code you have been assembling (i.e. post a [mcve]).  I can't possibly know what you forgot to correct and where and I can't tell you what exactly is wrong if I only have a fuzzy description of what your code might look like.

Answer (score 3):

So, thanks to @fuz, there shouldn't be any colons after the `sections`.
That means `section .data:` should be `section .data`. Same for `.bss` and `.text`.